# Rails has_many :throught breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Ok this is the error that I have

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* 
FROM `users` INNER JOIN `events` ON `users`.`id` = `events`.`author_id`  
WHERE `events`.`user_id` = 1
```

The line that generates this conflict is in the `user` model

```
has_many :events_created, :through => :events, :source => :author
```

All in all I know that the above error happens because in the `event` model there is the following line (which searches for a `events.user_id` in my db instead of the `events.author_id`

`belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"`

Is there any way to make it search for the `events.author_id` in this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "author_id"
```

Comment: Helpful, thanks the correct was: `has_many :events, :foreign_key => "author_id" has_many :events_created, :through => :events, :source => :author` in the user controller